# I want to customise the last layer of VGG 19 architecture for a classification. which will be more useful keras or pytorch?

Tags: keras, pytorch

I want to customise the last layer of VGG 19 architecture for a classification problem. which will be more useful keras or pytorch?

Comment: While it can be done in both, I would recommend PyTorch.

Comment: Please don't ask these kind of questions, they will only attract opinion answers.

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on what you want to do with it.
While Keras offers different backends, such as TensorFlow or Theano (which in turn can offer you a little more flexibility), and transfers better to production systems,
PyTorch is definitely also easy to implement. Additionally, it offers great scaling on (multi-)GPU systems, since it is trivial to outsource your computations in a PyTorch model. I do not know how easy that is in Keras (never done it, so I genuinely cannot judge).

If you just want to play around with one of the frameworks, it usually boils down to personal preference. I personally prefer PyTorch, due to its more "python-esque" approach to things, but I know many people that prefer Keras because of its clear and simple layout and documentation.

Providing a little more information, or your context, can also potentially increase the quality of the answers you receive.